# Proving validity when replacing every occurrence of a variable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have a problem finding a correct way to solve the next problem:
Let $φ$ be an argument with $n$-variables, $φ'$ is obtained from $φ$ by replacing every occurrence of a variable Vi by $¬$Vi, there is a need to prove: $φ$ is valid iff $φ'$ is valid.

I tried setting $φ$ as valid and using the rules ,mods($φ$)=World and mods($¬φ$)={} but I do not understand how will $φ'$ still be valid when we might change the premises themself by altering Vi to ¬Vi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the formula $¬\varphi$ is not the same as the formula $\varphi'$ obtained from $\varphi$ by replacing each variable by its negation. E.g., we have

$$¬(x \wedge y) \sim ¬x \vee ¬y.$$

Try to show that whenever $\varphi$ is satisfied under some valuation $v$, then $\varphi'$ is satisfied under the valuation $v'$ mapping each variable to true if $v$ maps it to false, and mapping to false if $v$ maps it to true. Then show that every valuation is of the form $v'$ for some $v$.

Comment: After i show such mapping i`ll be able to show that some of the premises switch their state when they are under φ vs φ′ ,but i still do not understand how will this help to show that the altered premises of φ′  will make it valid.

Comment: Valid means that the formula is true under every valuation. The first step is general, i.e., not assuming that $\varphi$ is valid, to investigate how $\varphi$ and $\varphi'$ are related. The second step establishes that $\varphi'$ is valid as follow. Let $w$ be a valuation. We want to show that $w$ makes $\varphi'$ true. To this end, write $w = v'$ for some valuation $v$ (which we can do by the second step). Since $\varphi$ is valid, $v$ makes $\varphi$ true. But then, by the first step, $v'$ makes $\varphi'$ true.

Comment: It seems that i still miss something.
Even if we write w=v′ for some valuation and establish that φ′ is valid, how does v  makes φ true when we did not assume that it is from the beggining.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't. For the second step, validity of $\varphi$ is necessary. Sorry for being unclear about this.